# After importing and using numpy, can no longer convert .py to .exe

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, exe

I wrote a simple script that takes user input and creates a .txt. My first iteration only wrote to the file and did not other work on the file. I added numpy library for the genfromtxt and find features. the code runs perfectly, but when I try to convert to an .exe file it will not package. The only additions to the script is numpy, and the previous version without it packaged without issue.

I'm a pretty novice coder and this may not be a numpy issue, but this is my best reasonable guess.

I have written other .py scripts and converted them to .exe that do not use numpy, and I don't have any issues. But those are not importing third party libraries...  This is why I believe it has something to do with numpy and the dependancies...

COMMAND LINE:
pyinstaller -y  "C:/Users/adamt/Desktop/QA Lot Tracking Application/QAInternalTrackingApp_v5.py"

Reproducing code example:
****NOT APPLICABLE: Error is in conversion from .py to .exe. The code runs fine in the editor (PyCharm).

OUTPUT from running command line:

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.6.5
Building in the current instances temporary directory at C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6a58x7u8
To get a new temporary directory, restart this application
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller -y  "C:/Users/adamt/Desktop/QA Lot Tracking Application/QAInternalTrackingApp_v5.py"
60089327 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
60089330 INFO: Python: 3.7.0
60089330 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
60089335 INFO: wrote C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6a58x7u8\QAInternalTrackingApp_v5.spec
60089348 INFO: UPX is not available.
60089373 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\adamt\\Desktop\\QA Lot Tracking Application',
 'C:\\Users\\adamt\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp6a58x7u8']
60089375 INFO: checking Analysis
60089375 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-01.toc is non existent
60089376 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
60089399 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
60089417 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
60093336 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-01.toc
60093340 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\program files\python37\python.exe
60094382 INFO: Caching module hooks...
60094400 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\adamt\Desktop\QA Lot Tracking Application\QAInternalTrackingApp_v5.py
60094981 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
60096595 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
60096596 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\adamt\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
60099890 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
60103279 INFO: Loading module hooks...
60103279 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
60103282 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
60103422 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-gevent.py"...
**60103726 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement greenlet from package gevent.
60103727 INFO: Packages required by gevent:
['cffi']**
60104984 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jinja2.py"...
60105008 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
60105017 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
An error occurred, traceback follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\__main__.py", line 269, in convert
    pyi.run() # Execute PyInstaller
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6a58x7u8\QAInternalTrackingApp_v5.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 502, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 410, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 377, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 793, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py", line 27, in <module>
    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths('numpy.core')
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 535, in get_package_paths
    file_attr = get_module_file_attribute(package)
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 318, in get_module_file_attribute
    loader = pkgutil.find_loader(package)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\pkgutil.py", line 493, in find_loader
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(fullname)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec
    parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

Comment: What version of numpy are you using? If it's the latest, try revert to an older version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54374323/1011724?

Comment: I have tried reverting to 1.17.0, no change in error. I also tried 1.16.0, also no change.

Comment: I also tried to turn a very simple .py script to .exe that uses "import pandas as pd", that will not convert to .exe either and it gives the same error.

Comment: it seems any external libraries or "modules?" will not package properly

Comment: But the link says to revert to 1.15.4...?

Comment: Another option would be to use entry points instead of pyinstaller. So you won't have an exe but rather a python package you can install using pip. But once installed, you will be able to call it from the command line as if you had yum/apt/brew installed it.

Comment: if your python 64bit try 32 bit